# Gson gives "unchecked conversion" warning

Tags: java, json, gson

I was trying to convert json strings to objects like this:

```
String jsonString = "[\"string1\", \"string2\"]";
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<String> list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, List.class);
```

There was this warning:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
            list = gson.fromJson(jsonString, List.class);
                                       ^
  required: List<String>
  found:    List
```

I tried to use `List<String>.class`

instead of `List.class` but I get a compile time error saying that I can't do that...

How can I get rid of this warning?

Comment: Uh, don't declare the variable as `List<String>`?

Comment: @HotLicks Good hint. In fact, as Reimeus mentioned, String[] works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an array

```
String[] array = gson.fromJson(jsonString, String[].class);
```

or using [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#collections-examples)

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
List<String> list  = gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```